# Is there a way to realize a function of type ((a -> b) -> b) -> Either a b?

Tags: haskell, logic

Propositions `(P -> Q) -> Q` and `P \/ Q` are equivalent.

Is there a way to witness this equivalence in Haskell:

```
from :: Either a b -> ((a -> b) -> b)
from x = case x of
         Left a -> \f -> f a
         Right b -> \f -> b

to :: ((a -> b) -> b) -> Either a b
to = ???
```

such that

`from . to = id` and `to . from = id`?

Comment: It seems obvious to me that this is impossible, but maybe I am wrong. If so, a useful starting point is that a function with thefully polymorphic type `((a -> b) -> b)` is isomorphic to `a`: the only possible implementation is `g f = f someHardcodedA`.

Comment: @amalloy there is another possible implementation: `g = const someHardcodedB`

Comment: Ah, of course. It is either `a` or `b`. Makes sense.

Comment: If Haskell had call/cc, then `to f = callcc (\k -> k (Right (f (\a -> k (Left a)))))` would work. (This is a valid classical proof of the implication.)

Answer (score 15):

> Propositions `(P -> Q) -> Q` and `P \/ Q` are equivalent.

This is true in classical logic, but not in the constructive logic.

In constructive logic we don't have [law of excluded middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle), i.e. we cannot start our thinking with "either P is true or P is not true".

Classically we reason like:

- if P is true (i.e we have (`x :: P`)) then return `Left x`.
- if P is false, then in Haskell speak we'd have `nx :: P -> Void` function. Then `absurd . nx :: P -> Q` (we can peak any type, we take `Q`) and call given `f :: (P -> Q) -> Q)` with `absurd . nx` to get value of type `Q`.

The problem, that there aren't general function of a type:

```
lem :: forall p. Either p (p -> Void)
```

For some concrete types there are, e.g. `Bool` is inhabited so we can write

```
lemBool :: Either Bool (Bool -> Void)
lemBool = Left True -- arbitrary choice
```

but again, in general we cannot.

Answer (score 9):

No, it is impossible. Consider the special case where `Q = Void`.

`Either P Q` is then `Either P Void`, which is isomorphic to `P`.

```
iso :: P -> Either P Void
iso = Left

iso_inv :: Either P Void -> P
iso_inv (Left p)  = p
iso_inv (Right q) = absurd q
```

Hence, if we had a function term

```
impossible :: ((P -> Void) -> Void) -> Either P Void
```

we could also have a term

```
impossible2 :: ((P -> Void) -> Void) -> P
impossible2 = iso_inv . impossible
```

According to the Curry-Howard correspondence, this would be a tautology in *intuitionistic* logic:

```
((P -> False) -> False) -> P
```

But the above is double negation elimination, which is well known to be impossible to prove in *intuitionistic* logic -- hence a contradiction. (The fact that we could prove it in *classical* logic is not relevant.)

(Final note: this assumes that out Haskell program terminate. Of course, using infinite recursion, `undefined`, and similar ways to actually avoid to return a result, we can inhabit any type in Haskell.)

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not possible, but it's a bit subtle. The problem is that the type variables `a` and `b` are universally quantified.

```
to :: ((a -> b) -> b) -> Either a b
to f = ...
```

`a` and `b` are universally quantified.  The caller chooses what type they are, so you can't just create a value of either type.  This implies you can't just create a value of type `Either a b` while ignoring the argument `f`.  But using `f` is also impossible.  Without knowing what types `a` and `b` are, you can't create a value of type `a -> b` to pass to `f`. There's just not enough information available when the types are universally quantified.

As far as why the isomorphism doesn't work in Haskell - are you sure those propositions are equivalent in a constructive intuitionist logic? Haskell does not implement a classical deductive logic.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, this is impossible because we don't have the law of the excluded middle. Let me go through that a bit more explicitly. Suppose we have

```
bogus :: ((a -> b) -> b) -> Either a b
```

and we set `b ~ Void`. Then we get

```
-- chi calls this `impossible2`.
double_neg_elim :: ((a -> Void) -> Void) -> a
bouble_neg_elim f = case bogus f of
             Left a -> a
             Right v -> absurd v
```

Now, let's prove the double negation of the law of the excluded middle *as applied to a specific proposition*.

```
nnlem :: forall a. (Either a (a -> Void) -> Void) -> Void
nnlem f = not_not_a not_a
  where
    not_a :: a -> Void
    not_a = f . Left

    not_not_a :: (a -> Void) -> Void
    not_not_a = f . Right
```

So now

```
lem :: Either a (a -> Void)
lem = double_neg_elim nnlem
```

`lem` clearly cannot exist because `a` can encode the proposition that any Turing machine configuration I happen to pick will halt.

---

Let's verify that `lem` is sufficient:

```
bogus :: forall a b. ((a -> b) -> b) -> Either a b
bogus f = case lem @a of
  Left a -> Left a
  Right na -> Right $ f (absurd . na)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what whether this is valid in terms of logic, or what it means for your equivalence, but yes it is possible to write such a function in Haskell.

To construct an `Either a b`, we need either an `a` or a `b` value. We don't have any way to construct an `a` value, but we do have a function that returns a `b` that we could call. To do that, we need to supply a function that converts an `a` into a `b`, but given the types are unknown we could at best make a function that returns a constant `b`. To get that `b` value, we can't construct it any other way than before, so this becomes circular reasoning - and we can solve that by simply creating a **fixpoint**:

```
to :: ((a -> b) -> b) -> Either a b
to f = let x = f (\_ -> x) in Right x
```